# How to check the key of next index of arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an PHP array :

```
$datas = array(
    "abcd" => array(
        "1639340364" => 1,
        "1639362752" => 85,
        "1639363500" => 74,
    ),
          
    "efgh" => array(
        "1639340364" => 78,
        "1639362754" => 98,
        "1639363500" => 46,
    ),
      
    
    "ijkl" => array(
        "1639340364" => 78,
        "1639362754" => 98,
        "1639363505" => 46,
    ),
);
```

I want to check the keys of each array and if not match need to add it on every array.

Expecting output like:

```
$datas = array(
      
    "abcd" => array(
        "1639340364" => 1,
        "1639362752" => 85,
        "1639362754" => 0,
        "1639363500" => 74,
        "1639363505" => 0,
    ),
          
    
    "efgh" => array(
          
        
        "1639340364" => 78,
        "1639362752" => 0,
        "1639362754" => 98,
        "1639363500" => 46,
        "1639363505" => 0,
    ),
      
    
    "ijkl" => array(
        "1639340364" => 78,
        "1639362752" => 0,
        "1639362754" => 98,
        "1639363500" => 0,
        "1639363505" => 46,
    ),
);
```

If the key is not exist need to add the key with value zero. Is that possible?

I tried with array_key_exists() function...
But I'm not sure where I want to check, when I'm checking It's return true(1). I know it's checking on the same array, Actually I want to know where I will check the condition?

```
foreach($datas as $key => $data ){
  print_r($data);
  foreach($data as $key => $point ){
    $val = array_key_exists($key,$data);
    echo $val;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is usually considered good form to show us what attempts to made to solve your problem. It doesn't need to work, or be any good, it is just an indication to us that you are really stuck even though you tried to solve your problem rather than just demand code without wanting to put in the effort yourself (which is what this current question is coming across as ).

Comment: *" Is that possible in PHP?"* This is *possible* in any programming language. Your question however doesn't seem to mention what the "input" is, only desired output?

Comment: @apokryfos Updated the question, at least give me a hint for how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
// prepare default keys
$keys = [];
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($data));
}
$keys = array_unique($keys);
sort($keys);

// construct default array with zeros
$default = array_combine($keys, array_fill(0, count($keys), 0));

// insert the default array
foreach ($datas as $key => $data) {
    $datas[$key] = array_replace($default, $data);
}

// show result
echo '<pre>';
print_r($datas);
echo '</pre>';
```

I needed used a plethora of array functions. The idea is this: First I gather all the possible 'keys' from the array, make them unique, sort them and combine them into a new 'default' array containing only zero values. After that I use the [array_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) function to insert this array into the existing `$datas` array. This function does exactly what you want:

> **array_replace()** replaces the values of **array** with values having the
> same keys in each of the following arrays. If a key from the first
> array exists in the second array, its value will be replaced by the
> value from the second array.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty or optimised, but here you go:

```
$subkeys = array();
foreach ($datas as $k => $d) {
    foreach($d as $k2 => $d2) {
        $subkeys[$k2] = 0;
    }
}
foreach ($datas as $k => &$d) {
    foreach ($subkeys as $xk => $xd) {
        if ( ! array_key_exists($xk, $d)) {
            $d[$xk] = $xd;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more optimal than you might think. You forgot to sort the subkeys before using them. An explanation would also be nice.